# Excel VBA copy columns from another workbook when specific criteria is set

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA coding. What I'm trying to do is the following:

A Workbook 1. cell (B2) can have different regions in, example "Inland". When it's "Inland" I need to copy 2 columns from Workbook 2, under the "Inland" heading and paste them in Workbook 1, different tab and column.
If it Workbook 1. cell B2="WC", I need to copy 2 columns under the "WC" heading in Workbook 2 and paste in Workbook 1 again, etc.

I don't want to write all the possible options because I know it's possible to copy just the data that matches that cell.

Example:
Workbook 1
     A        B
1 Region    Inland

Workbook 2
     A  B      C   D       E   F
1   Inland      WC          KZN
2 GC1 Leni    WC1 Kate    KF1 Jake
3 GF1 Paul    WC2 Esti    KF2 Els

Thus:
I if Inland specified in Workbook 1, I only need to copy A2:B3 from Workbook 2
If WC specified, I copy C2:D3.

I hope it's clear and understandable. Thank you.

Comment: 1) Welcome to SO. 2) Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to receive effective help on this site (current question as written will receive little to no response. 3) There are a bazillion questions on SO just like this if you search around a bit.

Comment: Hi Scott, I've been through a couple of other questions but I haven't found something specifically to help my problem. I see my question posted differently than how I typed it, which makes it very difficult to read I understand

Comment: Its less about readability (that can be fixed with formatting). It's more about that you have not shown any effort (if any) you have made to code to your solution and where it's failing.